# Please advise how to show JS variable value in HTML, specially URL

Tags: javascript, html, variables, url

Automatically change URL to show a image in different servers with one source code.

With one source code, I provide service to 2 companies which has their own server. For instance, One is a.example.com, the other is b.example.com. However, their company logo images are different. But the logos are same name with "login2.png" in "a.example.com:8080/images/login2.png" and 
"b.example.com:8080/images/login2.png". Is there any way how to make it like "_link/images/login2.png"? Then, I don't need to change the logo manually, whenever updated coded is deployed to each server. Thank you in advance

```
    <script>
        var link = window.location.origin;
        document.getElementById("_link").innerHTML=link;
    </script>
    <img src= ""_link"/images/login2.png">
```

Automatically change URL to show a image in different servers with one source code.

Answer (score 0):

using relative File Path

Relative file path points to a file relative to the current page.

```
    <img src= "/images/login2.png">
```

When you navigate  to a.example.com
Browser will render 
a.example.com:8080/images/login2.png"

And When you navigate  to b.example.com
Browser will render b.example.com:8080/images/login2.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use [window.location.hostname](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) to get the hostname and use it as you like instead of `_link`.